# How to do Click + Modifier with PhantomJs + Selenium/Arquillian?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, jboss-arquillian

In an automated web UI test I am writing using Selenium/Arquillian, I have to perform a control click on an item in a web page. I tried the following two approaches:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(item, xOffset, yOffset);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
actions.click();
actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
actions.build().perform();
```

and

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(item, xOffset, yOffset);
actions.click();
actions.build().perform();
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

They both work in Chrome and Firefox as expected. In PhantomJS however the click behaves like a usual click without the CTRL modifier. Is there something I am missing or some other way to get this to work?

Comment: Although this is not in the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html), but according to [code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp), mouse modifiers are supported. You should recreate your script with pure Selenium and if it still doesn't work, with vanilla PhantomJS to determine an which point it stops working.